# react native insertion of array values using react-native-sqlite-storage

Tags: android-sqlite, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

i am trying to insert array values into some table for sqlite. my arrays values are not inserted. i am strucked here that was i tried can you guide me in correct way here i am getting the response from axion json output.
response.zonedetails is a array.
        for (var i = 0; i < response.zoneDetails.length; i++){

```
      console.log('hi i am ');
      console.log('for loop log',response.zoneDetails[i]);

        var zoneNmae = response.zoneDetails[i].zonename;
        var parentZoneId = response.zoneDetails[i].parentzoneid;
        var levelId = response.zoneDetails[i].levelid;
        var zoneId = response.zoneDetails[i].zoneid;

   await this.setState({zonename: zoneNmae});
   await this.setState({zoneId:zoneId});
   await this.setState({parentzoneid: parentZoneId });
   await this.setState({levelid:levelId});
   this.initZonesDB();
   //this.addZonesdetailsInfo(response.zoneDetails);
   this.addZonesdetailsInfo();
```

this is my response :"zoneDetails": [
        {
            "zonename": "zone1",
            "zoneid": 1,
            "parentzoneid": 10,
            "levelid": "2"
        },
        {
            "zonename": "zone2",
            "zoneid": 2,
            "parentzoneid": 10,
            "levelid": "2"
        },

i am unable to insert all values every time,it was inserting first array of 1st index values only [0]. can any one suggest me to insert all values in good way for react native.

Comment: i am trying to insert the array values in mysqlite , using react-native-sqlite-storage can any one guide me how to save the values in table.

Comment: my response was"zoneDetails": [
        {
            "zonename": "zone1",
            "zoneid": 1,
            "parentzoneid": 10,
            "levelid": "2"
        },
        {
            "zonename": "zone2",
            "zoneid": 2,
            "parentzoneid": 10,
            "levelid": "2"
        },
        {
            "zonename": "zone3",
            "zoneid": 3,
            "parentzoneid": 10,
            "levelid": "2"
        },

Comment: my code addZonesdetailsInfo() {
          this.initZonesDB().then((db) => {
            db.transaction((tx) => {
              tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO zoneDetailsinfo VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', [this.state.zonename,this.state.zoneid,this.state.parentzoneid,this.state.levelid]).then(([tx, results]) => {
                resolve(results);
                console.log("device data inserted");
              });
            
            }).then((result) => {
              this.closeDatabase(db);
            }).catch((err) => {
   console.log(err); });}).catch((err) => { console.log(err);});}